# Xamarin Forms Load Resources on startup

Tags: xamarin.forms

I have an Xamarin Forms app with MvvmCross for Android and IOS and I would like to add a dark theme. My idea was to have to dictionaries with the ressources for either the dark or the light theme and load the one I need on startup.

I added this after I registered the dependencies in my MvxApplication:

```
        if (Mvx.IoCProvider.Resolve<ISettingsManager>().Theme == AppTheme.Dark)
        {
            Application.Current.Resources.Add(new ColorsDark());
        }
        else
        {
            Application.Current.Resources.Add(new ColorsLight());
        }
```

`ColorsDark` and `ColorsLight` are my ResourceDictionary. After that i can see the new Dictionary under `Application.Current.Resources.MergedDictionaries` but the controls can't find the resources as it seems. However it does work when I add it to the App.xaml

```
      <ResourceDictionary Source="Style/ColorsDark.xaml" />
```

Do I have to put move that another part in the code or is that a wrong approach at all?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Personally don't like this approach at all. What i do: have a static class with all the colors, sizes etc. defined in static fields. At app startup or at app reload after changing skin just call ex: `UiSettings.Init()` for this ui definitions static class, like follows:

```
public static class UiSettings
{       
      public static Init()
      {
            if (Settings.AppSettings.Skin=="butterfly")
            {
             ColorButton = Color.Blue;
             TitleSize= 12.0;
            }
            else
            if (Settings.AppSettings.Skin=="yammy")
            {
             ColorButton = Color.Red;
             if (Core.IsAndroid)
                ButtonsMargin = new Thickness(0.5,0.6,0.7,0.8);
            }
            // else just use default unmodified field default values 
        }

        public static Color ColorButton = Color.Green;
        public static Thickness ButtonsMargin = new Thickness(0.3,0.3,0.2,0.2);
        public static double TitleSize= 14.0;

}
```

in XAML use example:

```
 Color= "{x:Static xam:UiSettings.ColorProgressBack}"
```

in code use example:

```
Color = UiSettings.ColorProgressBack;
```

**UPDATE:**
Remember that if you access a static class from different assemblies it is possible that you will access a fresh copy of it with default values where Init() didn't happen, if you face such case call Init() from this assembly too.

Comment: Thanks. That works quite nice so far. But how do you accomplish that it does reload when you call it again? I tried DynamicResources instead of x:Static but that didn't work.

Comment: Alright, I kinda figured it out. When I set a default value it will set it correclty on startup. But I still have to restart the app to make a new selected style apply-

Comment: yes i restart the app by setting mainpage = pageShowingRestarting, then mainpage = yourUsualMainPage. do not forget to do a cleanup before it, unsubscribing from messages etc

Comment: Also useful for changing language at runtime

Comment: I see. How do you use them in Styles for example for texts? I bound the color there using x:Static, DynamicResources and x:DynamicResources but in all cases it just takes the default value I set but not the updated I set when loading the app.

Comment: this is not normal that updated values are wiped, but pls check my updated answer

Comment: also call init as soon as possible, at the app.xaml.cs start for example, so that all pages that are created use initialized values

Comment: You are right with both points. I had the static class in a different assembly. Also I had to place it before the InitializeComponent in the app.xaml.cs so that the colors are available when the styles are initialized.

Answer (score 0):

If you want something to load up when your app loads then you have to code it in App.xaml.cs

```
protected override void OnStart ()
    {
        if (Mvx.IoCProvider.Resolve<ISettingsManager>().Theme == AppTheme.Dark)
        {
            Application.Current.Resources.Add(new Xamarin.Forms.Style(typeof(ContentPage))
            {
                ApplyToDerivedTypes = true,
                Setters = {
                new Xamarin.Forms.Setter { Property = ContentPage.BackgroundImageProperty, Value = "bkg7.png"},
            }
            });
        }
        else
        {
            Application.Current.Resources.Add(new Xamarin.Forms.Style(typeof(ContentPage))
            {
                ApplyToDerivedTypes = true,
                Setters = {
                new Xamarin.Forms.Setter { Property = ContentPage.BackgroundImageProperty, Value = "bkg7.png"},
            }
            });
        }
    }
```

In this code I'm setting the BackgroungImage of all of my pages. Hope you'll get the idea from this code.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I moved my code to the app.xaml.cs but that didn't change anything. You define the style directly in code. Is there a way to load a Ressource Dictionary that way?

Comment: Yes. Just place the Resource Dictionary In app.xaml

Comment: I mean to load them dynamically. When I load them in the app.xaml they are static, aren't they?

Comment: Save your style or colors using Settings plugin and load them up whenever your app loads.